# Slow MySQL query with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, performance, eloquent

I'm using Laravel Eloquent and debuging why this query is taking so long:

```
select count(*) as aggregate 
from `custom_products` 
where `hidden` = '0' 
and (`company_id` = '1')
and exists (
   select * from `categories` 
   inner join `categorizables` on `categories`.`id` = `categorizables`.`category_id` 
   where `custom_products`.`id` = `categorizables`.`categorizable_id`
   and `categorizables`.`categorizable_type` = 'App\Models\CustomProduct' 
   and `categories`.`deleted_at` is null) 
and exists (
   select * from `images` 
   where `custom_products`.`id` = `images`.`imageable_id` 
   and `images`.`imageable_type` = 'App\Models\CustomProduct' 
   and `images`.`deleted_at` is null) 
and `custom_products`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Sometimes it runs very slow: it tooks 17.46s to run as you see in this image from debugbar:

[image: print of debugbar]

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Use `explain` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) to figure out which query running slow and optimize it

Comment: That's classic eloquent for you. Do an explain as @Ben said and then redo the query using joins and do an explain again. Marvel at the speed difference. After that move to query builder and don't look back. The bigger your table gets the worse it gets. BTW do you have indexes set on the tables? That counts as well

Comment: Rafael you are doing 2 'exists' queries which are actually subqueries AND you are doing a select* in both. Can you make better joins of those subqueries and maybe filter out the results with a where()

Answer (score 1):

`images`.`imageable_id` is that the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

What indexes are there on `custom_products`?  It needs

```
INDEX(company_id, hidden, deleted_at)
```

On a different topic, I think you have a bug in `'App\Models\CustomProduct'` -- backslash is the escape character, not a directory separator.  Probably you need `'App\\Models\\CustomProduct'`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add these indexes to optimize the query:

```
ALTER TABLE `categories` ADD INDEX `categories_idx_at_id` (`deleted_at`,`id`);
ALTER TABLE `categorizables` ADD INDEX `categorizables_idx_type_id_id` (`categorizable_type`,`category_id`,`categorizable_id`);
ALTER TABLE `custom_products` ADD INDEX `custom_products_idx_hidden_id_at` (`hidden`,`company_id`,`deleted_at`);
ALTER TABLE `custom_products` ADD INDEX `custom_products_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `images` ADD INDEX `images_idx_type_at_id` (`imageable_type`,`deleted_at`,`imageable_id`);
```